# Unable to set user defined values for id column in cosmos db collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I m trying to set user defined values in **document id** of cosmos db for this i am trying to use **spark with java**  but i am unable to do that any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: _i am trying to use spark with java but i am unable to do that_ ... please include your code and (error message?) so that your question gets more specific and others can help you effectively. (For reference, see also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to, with "user defined values in document id" - please edit your question to clarify what, exactly, this means. And as @IvoMori mentioned, sample code (and sample data) would be very helpful in trying to understand your issue.

Comment: Also: Please edit your tags to clarify which Cosmos DB API you're using. Currently, you have both the native SQL API tagged and the MongoDB API.